# Drupal role w/ access to translated pages only

Tags: drupal, internationalization, permissions

I am trying to set up a role that only has access to edit translated pages. Do I need a module for this or can I use core to get this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Drupal doesn't distinguish between languages natively, but I believe [this module](http://drupal.org/project/translation_management) introduces the roles you're after.

Comment: +1 I can't confirm this for sure, but it appears that the Translation Management module you mention works, creating the Translator role.

Comment: Yes, this is what the project page claims at least: creating a Translator role with rights to translate between a given pair of languages. I can't confirm this either though, but I'll be happy to hear about the results.